# How select the selector from its method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

I need to change the text of '#foo #three' using 'this' to get the text of the div#one

The output I need is:

- cat
- dog
- cat

Html:

```
<div id="foo">
 <div id="one">cat</div>
 <div id="two">dog</div>
 <div id="three">mouse</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#foo #three").text($(this).parent().children().first().text());
```

I need this code dynamically

http://jsfiddle.net/Kodam/s466a31q/

Comment: `$("#foo #three")` will return *one* element.  What *exactly* are you trying to do?  Do you want `$("#foo #three").text($('#foo div:first').text());`?  (Or, better yet: `$('#three").text($('#one').text());`) There's no way to reference a previous selector in another one.

Comment: But the context of `this` never changed. What are you really trying to do? Also, why are you selecting by more than one `id`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat OP is saying they want to copy `li#one` to `li#three`; that list is the final output.

Comment: maybe you want `$("#foo #three").text($(this).text());`, although it changes absolutely nothing...

Comment: P.S. `$('this')` will look for a `<this>` tag.

Comment: Hi, sry I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#three").text($('#foo').children().first().text());
```

Update: If you really want to use this to reference the match, would recommend to use each:

```
$("#foo #three").each(function(){ // this only matches #three
  $(this).text($(this).parent().children().first().text());  
})
```

Comment: Your answer works. So there isn't a way to use $(this) inside the method text() like this?  $("#foo #three").text($(this).parent().children().first().text());

Comment: Nope, closest I know of is what I posted

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are trying to do this dynamically, this is as simple as:

```
$('#three').text($('#one').text());
```

Comment: sry, yes, this is dinamically

Comment: Can you demonstrate your dynamic setup? What you're asking for right now doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I need to change 'mouse' for 'cat' going from '#foo #three' to his parent and then select the text of its first children. I updated the question already.

Comment: I tried this $("#foo #three").text($(this).parent().children().first().text()); but it doesnt works

Comment: Of course it doesn't; `this` probably refers to the `window`. Can you explain __why__ you need to do it this way? You are asking how to achieve a specific (nonsensical) solution instead of presenting what _problem_ you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Though this approach uses a kind of workaround, it works:

```
$jSelect = $("#foo #three");
$jSelect.text( function(){
var jParts = $jSelect.selector.split(" ");
  return $(jParts[0]).find("div:first").text();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/sf8an7ru/)

But I wouldn't recommend it as `.selector` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and only maintained for supporting `live()` in the jQuery Migrate plugin.
For Reference: http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Update: And a similar approach without using `.selector`:

```
jSelect = ("#foo #three");
$(jSelect).text( function(){
 var jParts = jSelect.split(" ");
 return $(jParts[0]).find("div:first").text();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/sf8an7ru/3/)

Comment: I updated the question. Furthermore I prefer not use 'selector'.

Comment: @DocKodam Updated answer with version not using ".selector"

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using `this`, you can do it this way:

<kbd>**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/u4njvp58/)**</kbd>

basically, since `this` only works inside a function context, you create a function that returns a string and put it inside the `.text()`.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#foo #three").text(function () {
        return $(this).parent().children().first().text();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
    <div id="one">cat</div>
    <div id="two">dog</div>
    <div id="three">mouse</div>
</div>
```